# IE compatibility mode: strong tag= different width on different PCs?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, width

I have a case in which text inside a strong tag, is rendered with different widths on different Windows PCs.
I've checked the style with dev tool, they have the same font-family. DOC TYPE is at the beginning of document.
Other browsers are consistent (rule out font differences on PCs).

I understand that different browsers calculate things differently, but I wonder what is the problem with different PCs...

It seems however that font-weight:bold gives equal widths. 
I see also that Chrome assignes a font-weight:bold to strong, from user-agent style sheet.
I don't know about IE.
I'll try to put a strong {font-family:bold} in my style sheet.

Anyone has exeperienced  important style differences across different PCs?

thx

Comment: Have you checked the ClearType font smoothing settings? They could be different on the different PCs. Also, IE9 has its own font smoothing style which is different from IE8 and earlier, even on the same PC.

Answer (score 2):

There is some cases that explain the difference, the render of the `<strong>` tag and font in the page may differ between versions of Windows.

A Firefox 3.6 on Windows XP and the same Firefox on Windows 7 should have some fonts differences because the native fonts installed in windows may be different. Be careful on the Service Pack versions too, it may differ from that as well.

Have you checked the default theme/font used on the both windows ? Have you checked if all the defaults of the browsers you test have been reset ? (font size, font style)... Is there a font smooth used software installed ? (like a skin or a theme ?). Like 'daGUY' as said, also check the ClearType.

I think the problem doesn't come from your code but from the font installed on the PC and i think it's the normal behavior you see.

What you should do for testing is apply your own font by using CSS `@font-face`. You will be sure that the font used is the same between computers. But the render should differ too.